# While loop for java file transfer not exiting

Tags: java, while-loop, client-server, file-transfer

I am writing a program that will eventually transfer files both from client to server and from server to client, however the while loop (marked with **) for the client to receive a file from the server will not exit. I have posted both the client.java and server.java files, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Client.java

```
class Client{
    public static void main(String srgs[])throws IOException
    {
    Socket s=null;
    BufferedReader get=null;
    PrintWriter put=null;
    int userOption = 0;
    String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    try
    { 
        s=new Socket("localhost",5000);
        get=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        put=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);        
    }  
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    do{
        InputStreamReader get3=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Choose from the following options:");
        System.out.println("(1) Upload file to server");
        System.out.println("(2) Download File to server");
        System.out.println("(3) Exit application");
        BufferedReader dis1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        userOption=Integer.parseInt(dis1.readLine());
        put.println(userOption);    
        
        
        switch(userOption)
        {
            
            case 1:
                //upload file code here
                
                break;
                
            case 2:
                InputStreamReader get2=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
                String u,f;
                System.out.println("Enter the file name to transfer from server:");
                BufferedReader dis=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                f=dis.readLine();
                put.println(f);
                File f1=new File(cwd +"\\"+ f);
                FileOutputStream  fs=new FileOutputStream(f1);

                BufferedInputStream d=new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f1));
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                
                **while((read = d.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    outStream.flush();
                }**
                
                fs.close();
                System.out.println("File received");
                
                break;
        }
        
    } while (userOption != 3);
    s.close();
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server {   
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    { 
        ServerSocket ss=null;
        try
        {  
            ss=new ServerSocket(5000);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        { 
            System.out.println("couldn't listen");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Socket cs=null;
        try
        { 
            cs=ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established"+cs);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 
            System.out.println("Accept failed");
            System.exit(1);
        } 
        while(true)
        {
        PrintWriter put1=new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader st1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
        int s1=Integer.parseInt(st1.readLine());
        
            switch(s1)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("The client has requested to upload a file");
                    break;
                
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("The client has requested to download a file");
                    PrintWriter put=new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
                    BufferedReader st=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
                    String s=st.readLine();
                    System.out.println("The requested file is : "+s);
                    File f=new File(s);
                        if(f.exists())
                        { 
    
                            BufferedInputStream d=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(s));
                            BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
                            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                            int read;
                            while((read = d.read(buffer))!=-1)
                            {
                                outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                outStream.flush();
                            }
                            d.close();
                            System.out.println("File transfered");
                        }
                    break;
                
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("The client has been terminated");
                    return;
                
                default:
                    System.out.println("The client has entered an invalid option");
                    break;
            }  
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is the client entering into the loop at all? I mean, first you need to be sure you are getting at least. It might be blocked in the `read() `for ever. And that would indicate an error on de server side.

Comment: Yes, I checked and it does enter the while loop and gets the file, it just won't exit it.

Comment: It wonders me why you did it right in the server class and wrong in the client class ?! Why not making it !=-1 as well? 

Comment: I originally had it as !=-1 in the Client.java but that was also not working so I was just trying something different

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same file name in both the programs and when you run both of them from the same directory you will have this issue as the file will get created (again) and overwritten with zero bytes by the `Client`. You can use different file names or run the programs in different directories.

Comment: When I run this program the client is being run on my local machine, and the server is being run on a separate server so they aren't being run in the same directory. This shouldn't the the issue then, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I notice that, you are keeping the data connection open hence client does not know that the file transfer is over. A simple solution is to close the connection i.e. use `cs.close()` after `d.close()`. In this case you need to re-establish the connection for another file transfer. In another approach, you can keep the connection alive but the server has to indicate the client that the data transfer is over. This is where the different protocol design over TCP/IP (such as HTTP) come in picture.